# What is the equivalent of 'info frame' for lldb?

Tags: gdb, lldb

I try to use `lldb` the LLVM debugger, but I am quite used to `gdb`. So, I am looking for the equivalent of the `gdb` command `info frame` for `lldb`.

I want to display information about the current frame with the location of the saved registers (saved program counter and saved base pointer). For example, the `info frame` command of `gdb` display the following information:

```
Stack level 0, frame at 0x7fffffffe090:
 rip = 0x4004ba in main (example.c:6); saved rip = 0x7ffff7a54b45
 source language c.
 Arglist at 0x7fffffffe080, args: 
 Locals at 0x7fffffffe080, Previous frame's sp is 0x7fffffffe090
 Saved registers:
  rbp at 0x7fffffffe080, rip at 0x7fffffffe088
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There isn't a command that presents all this information at a blow.  Some of it is easily available to you, for instance:

```
(lldb) frame variable -L
```

Will show you the location of args & locals - though it will show you values as well.  The frame printing generally shows the `pc` and source info, and `reg read sp` will show the stack pointer.  Or you can add `fp` & `sp` to your regular frame format (see this [page](http://lldb.llvm.org/formats.html) for more details).

There is a `frame info` command that shows a fairly simple view of the current frame.  It could certainly be extended to show more of this info (maybe under a `-v` flag.)  Feel free to file a bug with `lldb.llvm.org`'s bugzilla requesting this, or dive in and add it yourself if you feel so motivated.

It wouldn't be hard to write a Python command to gather all this information and present it as you would like if you are somewhat motivated, but not enough to start hacking on `lldb` proper.

Comment: Ok, I was suspecting that there was no equivalent because I couldn't find anything despite my search... Thanks a lot for the pointers and the hints to get more information about the frame.